# AWS iam create new user returning html instead of xml response android

Tags: android, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am creating a new user through android app programatically using amazon web-service.
here is my code(asynctask):

```
private class S3RegisterNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            ProgressDialog dialog;
            String email;
             public S3RegisterNewUser(String email) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                this.email=email;
            }


            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(S3UploaderActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage(S3UploaderActivity.this
                        .getString(R.string.plswait));
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();
            }


            protected String doInBackground(String ...strings) {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.REGISTER); //url[0]

                    String result = "";
                    boolean result_recvd = false;
                    boolean ifallset = false;

//                  sparser = new ParsingClass();

                    try {
                      // Add your data
                      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName",email));
                      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Path","/"));
                      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Version","2010-05-08"));


                      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                   // Execute HTTP Post Request
                      /*HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                      is = entity.getContent();
                      bindDataToListing(is);*/

                      HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
                      ist = ent.getContent();
                      result = getStringFromInputStream(ist);



                      if(!result.contains("result")) {
                          Toast.makeText(S3UploaderActivity.this, "No connection or data not received from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          //result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><xml><result>0</result><message>"+Constants.noConnection+"</message></xml>";
                          result_recvd = false;
                      }else{
                          /** Result has been received from server which contains atleast the 'result' TAG 
                           *  This helps us to know if data is being fetched from server or not.*/
                          result_recvd = true;
                      }

                     // ifallset = bindDataToListing(result, result_recvd);

                      if(!result.contains("result")){
                          Toast.makeText(S3UploaderActivity.this, "No connection or data not received from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }

                      //result = convertStreamtoString(is);

                      Log.e("-- parseResultXML: ", ""+result);

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }  catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                    System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, " +
                            "which means the client encountered " +
                            "an internal error while trying to communicate" +
                            " with S3, " +
                            "such as not being able to access the network.");
                    System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                dialog.dismiss();


            }


        }

          /** Convert input stream to a String 
         * @param is -Supply the input stream variable here */
        private String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null ) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

**Constants.REGISTER="https://iam.amazonaws.com/"**

I am following the Iam [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUser.html).But instead of recieving xml result according to the documentation I am recieving **HTML responses** like below:

```
06-20 15:05:55.856: E/-- parseResultXML:(665): <!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 lang-en lang-en_US" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lang-en lang-en_US" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lang-en lang-en_US" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 9]><html class="no-js lt-ie10 lang-en lang-en_US" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js lang-en lang-en_US" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <!--<![endif]--> <head>   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//a1.awsstatic.com" />   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//a0.awsstatic.com" />   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//d0.awsstatic.com" />   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />   <title>AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) in the Cloud</title>   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />   <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="//a1.awsstatic.com/images/site/favicon.ico" />   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="//a1.awsstatic.com/images/site/favicon.ico" />   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="//a1.awsstatic.com/images/site/touch-icon-iphone-114-precomposed.png" />   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="//a1.awsstatic.com/images/site/touch-icon-ipad-144-precomposed.png" />   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="//a1.awsstatic.com/images/site/touch-icon-iphone-114-precomposed.png" />   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="//a1.awsstatic.com/images/site/touch-icon-ipad-144-precomposed.png" />   <meta property="og:title" content="AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) in the Cloud" />   <meta property="og:type" content="company" />   <meta property="og:url" content="//aws.amazon.com/iam/" />   <meta property="og:image" content="//a1.awsstatic.com/images/open-graph/opengraph.gif" />   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Amazon Web Services, Inc." />   <meta name="google-site-verification" content="XHghG81ulgiW-3EylGcF48sG28tBW5EH0bNUhgo_DrU" />   <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="6F92E52A288E266E30C2797ECB5FCCF3" />   <link rel="canonical" href="http://aws.amazon.com/iam/" />   <link rel="alternate" href="//aws.amazon.com/de/iam/" hreflang="de-de" />   <link rel="alternate" href="//aws.amazon.com/es/iam/" hreflang="es-es" />   <link rel="alternate" href="//aws.amazon.com/fr/iam/" hreflang="fr-fr" />   <link rel="alternate" href="//aws.amazon.com/jp/iam/" hreflang="ja-jp" />   <link rel="alternate" href="//aws.amazon.com/pt/iam/" hreflang="pt-br" />   <link rel="alternate" href="//aws.amazon.com/ko/iam/" hreflang="ko-kr" />   <link rel="alternate" href="//aws.amazon.com/cn/iam/" hreflang="zh-cn" />   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//a1.awsstatic.com/css/35/style.css" />   <!--[if lt IE 9]>    <script src="//a1.awsstatic.com/js/35/jquery.1.9.js"></script>  <![endif]-->   <!--[if (gte IE 9) | (!IE)]><!-->   <script src="//a1.awsstatic.com/js/35/jquery.2.0.js"></script>   <!--<![endif]-->   <script src="//a1.awsstatic.com/js/35/aws-target-mediator.js"></script>   <script>AWS.TargetMediator.init();</script>   <script src="//a1.awsstatic.com/js/35/modernizr.js"></script>   <script>    var require = {      baseUrl: "//a1.awsstatic.com/js/35/",      paths: {        "jquery": "jquery-amd"      },      deps: ["scripts"],      shim: {        "scripts": ["jquery"],        "forms": ["jquery"],        "pricing-table": ["jquery"
```

If I am doing something wrong or sending some wrong parameters then the code must throw an exception or stop.But why it is returning this HTML file??What wrong I am doing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

The AWS SDK for Android seems to be a bit lacking on the getting started front indeed - it seems to be designed fairly similar to the AWS SDK for Java though (naturally):

There, every AWS service has its own service specific client, which would be [AmazonIdentityManagementClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagementClient.html) for your use case. Given it is absent, it seems the AWS SDK for Android doesn't support IAM directly, so you'd need to resort to the *IAM Query API* indeed (as mentioned on that page), i.e. you'll need to implement the [Signing [of] AWS API Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) yourself, unfortunately.

---

#### Initial Answer

AWS services in general and [Amazon IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) in particular require the [Signing [of] AWS API Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html), i.e. you cannot simply call an API endpoint, rather you need your [AWS Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-security-credentials.html) to generate a [Digital Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) for each request before submitting it to the API.

The request signing process is a bit complex though and also varies between AWS services, so I'd highly recommend to simply use the [AWS SDK for Android](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/) instead, which does all the heavy lifting for you - this also applies for any other complexities in dealing with AWS btw., so even if you can conceptually, I'd actually never use AWS without a SDK if there isn't any specific reason to do so (e.g. being on a platform not supported by one of the many [offical AWS SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/) yet).

Comment: but here i am using aws sdk.

Comment: I have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321085/register-a-new-user-using-amazon-web-services-iam this in the morning.I have done all the other work,but I am unable to create new user in IAM programatically

Comment: Ah, hadn't realized, sorry - I've been confused by your use of the `DefaultHttpClient` rather than the [SdkHttpClient](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/4bff8f14a7fbea794486659d129abd6eda96120a/src/com/amazonaws/http/impl/client/SdkHttpClient.java) I would have expected to be mandatory when using the AWS SDK for Android?

Comment: Sir I think you and your team should think  about including this details in the AWS documentations.Anyway thank you so muck sir.So  I replaced   HttpClient with SdkHttpClient but what about HttpPost??

Comment: I'm not affiliated with AWS in any way, I'm just a heavy user and 3rd party AWS integration vendor. I agree that the documentation for the AWS Android SDK seems a bit lacking, esp. concerning getting started samples - usually I find my way around in seconds, and that's clearly not the case here, sorry for being misleading as a result. I've updated my answer with additional information on what I'm currently reading into the state of affairs regarding IAM support by the AWS SDK for Android.

Comment: I saw that sir...please provide me some samples of creating a new user through android app,using amazon IAM if you find any.I am in a real mess.

Comment: ...sir you are right.aws sdk for android does not support IAM